# NgModel not updating on first time onclick angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

I've got a strange problem with my angular5 application, I am trying to do simple form submit

**ts**

```
export class NewFormComponent implements OnInit {
  formSlug:'';

  newForm = { 
    title:"",
    description:" ", 
    allowMultiSubmit:""
  }

  //create new form
  createForms() {
      this.formsSandbox.createNewFormPartial(newForm).subscribe((result: any) => {
          console.log('created');
      });
  }


}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="new_form_wrap_body">
      <div class="new_form_content">
        <div class="new_form_content_row">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Title" class="new_form_input" [(ngModel)]="newForm.title">
        </div>
        <div class="new_form_content_row">
          <textarea class="new_form_textarea" [(ngModel)]="newForm.description" maxlength="250" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="new_form_content_row">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <div class="check_outer">
                    <input name="" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="newForm.allowMultiSubmit">
                    <div class="check" for="1_in"></div>
                  </div>
                </label>
                <span>Allow multiple submission</span>
              </div>

        </div>
        <!-- <div class="new_form_content_row">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Add Collaborators" class="new_form_short_input">
        </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="new_form_wrap_footer">
      <ul>
        <li>
 <button (click)="createForms()" class="new_form_footer_next">Create</button>
```

This works fine in development. When I pushed this on to testing server which served under apache (dist folder is uploaded ) `ngModel` is not updating values on `newForm` on the first click(trigger `createForms()`).On the second click  `newForm` is updated with form value

Does any one know why this is happening??

Comment: No errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in console that makes me sad:(

Comment: what is `formsSandbox` ?

Comment: @ashishpal its actually API call layer don't worry about it

Comment: 1 . make the variable `public` since you are using in template 2. Its always nice to initialize values using methods like  `ngOnInit() or constructor()`